# Salesforce to Netsuite Invalid loggin attempt error

Tags: salesforce, integration, netsuite, apex

I am facing the the below error while integrating sales order  with the netsuite from salesforce.

This issue is coming only for  one or two sales orders out of all. Can you share your thoughts in this point.

Error :- {"error" : {"code" : "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT", "message" : "Invalid login attempt."}}

We used the OAuth 1 authentication method

Thanks you.

Tried with other sales orders it worked.